# Sample CloudFormation code to enable Cross region replication on ECR with filter

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cli, amazon-ecr

I have to enable a cross-region replication for AWS ECR through cloud formation. For this, I have to add a rule and filter (optional ). Without the filter, I'll replicate all ECR to the target region. If I have to select only a few specific reports I have to add a filter.
This filter is kind of PREFIX_MATCH. But I don't see any example in AWS documentation to add a filter !!

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecr-replicationconfiguration.html

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Finally below is the cloud formation code ( in YAML ) which is working as expected. I have tested it!!

Let's say we have below 4 repositories on us-east-1

1. account-app1
2. account-app2
3. payment-app1
4. inventory-app1
   In the below example, the replication will enable only the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd repositories for two destinations us-east-2 and us-west-2.

**Note**:

1. The filter is optional, without the filter it will enable replication
   for all repositories.
2. The filter can be the full name of the repository.
   In case we need to enable only one or some specific repositories.

```YAML
Resources:
  MyReplicationConfig:
    Type: AWS::ECR::ReplicationConfiguration
    Properties:
      ReplicationConfiguration: 
          Rules:
            - Destinations:
                - Region: "us-east-2"
                  RegistryId: "123456789012"
                - Region: "us-west-2"
                  RegistryId: "123456789012"   
              RepositoryFilters:
                - FilterType: PREFIX_MATCH
                  Filter: account
                - FilterType: PREFIX_MATCH
                  Filter: payment
```

Comment: That yaml format is the same as the one I provided in json. You could easily convert it. But claim that you found the answer in yaml format. And if you bother to check the documentations you’ll see that filter is optional. You’ll see that filter can be string but also regex.

Comment: I can not attach a screenshot of the AWS console error here. I request you to try to add a filter yourself with regex and see. For me it's showing an error as "Filters should match the repository name format, must start with a letter and can only contain lowercase letters, numbers, hyphens, underscores and forward slashes. Filters must be between 2 and 256 characters.

Comment: I don't see any reason for negative voting for this answer as it's tested and working fine. Please leave a comment If further clarification is required.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example. I haven't tested it but this is how it looks like when you follow the documentation.

```
{
  "Resources": {
    "EcrReplication": {
      "Type": "AWS::ECR::ReplicationConfiguration",
      "Properties": {
        "ReplicationConfiguration": {
          "Rules": [
            {
              "Destinations": [ 
                {
                  "Region": "Region",
                  "RegistryId": "AwsAccountId"
                }
              ],
              "RepositoryFilters": [
                {
                  "Filter" : "^(?:[a-z0-9]+(?:[._-][a-z0-9]*)*/)*[a-z0-9]*(?:[._-][a-z0-9]*)*$",
                  "FilterType": "PREFIX_MATCH"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

- [AWS::ECR::ReplicationConfiguration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecr-replicationconfiguration.html)
- [AWS::ECR::ReplicationConfiguration ReplicationConfiguration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ecr-replicationconfiguration-replicationconfiguration.html)
- [AWS::ECR::ReplicationConfiguration ReplicationRule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ecr-replicationconfiguration-replicationrule.html)
- [AWS::ECR::ReplicationConfiguration ReplicationDestination](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ecr-replicationconfiguration-replicationdestination.html)
- [AWS::ECR::ReplicationConfiguration RepositoryFilter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ecr-replicationconfiguration-repositoryfilter.html)

Comment: I was looking for Cloud formation code in YAML formal, and I tested with the AWS UI console, it seems the filter doesn't support regex only, we need any repository prefix only. I'm posting my answer which I have tested, working as expected.